# Nginx configuration already exists/file missing

Tags: django, nginx

I am trying to host an application on AWS using Nginx and I am having issues with configuring my site configurations.

If i run

```
sudo ln /etc/nginx/sites-available/django.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

It shows

```
ln: failed to create hard link '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django.conf': File exists
```

If i run

```
sudo nginx -t
```

It shows

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
```

Not understanding the problem. Please help.

Comment: First command you're trying to create a link to a file that already exist, second command is telling you that somewhere in your nginx configurations you're referencing a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Andre.IDK what can i do now?

Comment: First try to solve the 2nd one, check the Nginx configurations and find where this `example.conf` is referenced and make sure it's needed, if not remove it. Then, understand if the `django.conf` file/link that is already there is needed or not and act accordingly.